# Cannot use Monitor mode in Kali using TP-LINK TL-WN722N

Tags: kali-linux, wireshark

I recently bought a **TP-LINK TL-WN722N** adapter that claims to support Monitor mode and captures any traffic using **Wireshark**. I tried using **Monitor mode** with the following commands in Kali Linux,

```
sudo ifconfig

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:26:22:04:49:62  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 11796  bytes 15836333 (15.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11796  bytes 15836333 (15.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.189  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::9dde:ace6:749e:e297  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2405:205:8505:632e:e48a:55c3:960:ab39  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether ec:08:6b:16:ce:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3979  bytes 3151582 (3.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3467  bytes 519376 (507.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

From this output, I know that my adapter was recognized as **wlan1**.

```
sudo iwconfig

wlan1     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Redmi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: AC:C1:EE:BC:17:51   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:13  Invalid misc:58   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

So, at present, the adapter is in **Managed mode**. I tried to turn ON Monitor mode with the following commands,

```
sudo airmon-ng check kill
sudo airmon-ng start wlan1
```

It indeed **turned ON Monitor mode** where I can see the results here,

```
sudo ifconfig

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:26:22:04:49:62  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 13672  bytes 18390290 (17.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13672  bytes 18390290 (17.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1mon: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec EC-08-6B-16-CE-88-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 1135  bytes 246511 (240.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and here,

```
sudo iwconfig

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan1mon  IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

By the way, result of **lsusb**,

```
lsusb

Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2150 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

This seems like a *dead end* now, I get **disconnected** from the Wifi network that I connect with. Everything related to Network disappears at the top right corner.

**Wireshark didn't capture anything**. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. Losing the previous connection when switching to monitor mode is normal/intended behaviour. The wifi PEN for monitor mode will be exclusively used for that function while in that mode.

If you need Internet connectivity/a remote shell while in monitor mode, you have to have a secondary connection, like an ethernet card, or a second USB wifi pen.

The chipset you are using seem also to be the correct one according to `lsusb` output.

I do suspect you are not getting any output *because* your remote session gets cuts as soon you enter monitor mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool XEye-tp, it will set your tp-link adapter to monitor mode in very short time.
The link to the tool: https://github.com/Engmostafa26/XEye-tp